# Great Britain's role in Islamic Iran

Tags: united-kingdom, iran

Before the World War Iran was a colony of Great Britain.
I am sure that the Islamization of today's Iran is the result of Great Britain's policy on Iran before the World War.
However, no data has been published on this issue.

What was Great Britain's role in the Islamization of today's Iran?

Comment: Welcome to the History Stack-exchange. I've edited your question for grammar and spelling, and I also changed your tag from England to the United Kingdom. I was unable to figure out which World War you were referring to, though think you are talking about WW2, so I just called it, "the World War." PS, I took out the flag section, as It doesn't really have much to do with the question.

Comment: Why is the flag linked to the question?  Am I missing some kind of relationship between the flag and the question?

Comment: @Max, I took that out, I though the same thing.

Comment: You might want to look at this answer: http://history.stackexchange.com/a/3053/114

Comment: @Russell The flag made it back?  I rejected an edit with that early on...weird, but I agree it didn't seem to fit the question

Answer (score 10):

Iran was never a British colony. British actions may have inadvertently aided the Islamization of Iran, though the most critical time period appears to me to be the Mossadegh government ('51-'53), not the Second World War or prior.

Also, you say

> I am sure that the Islamization of today's Iran is the result of Great Britain's policy on Iran before the World War. However, no data has been published on this issue.

You should not be sure of any such thing if you do not have any access to data! What gave you this impression initially?

Comment: An upvote for the defence of The Scientific Method.

Comment: An upvote to correct that bold OP's mistake in considering Iran as a colony of UK. Iran has never been a colony of any countries in the world over the history.

Answer (score 2):

Recently the Islamic Republic of Iran labelled BBC Persian Television a key tool of “soft power” being used to stir up the demonstrations which have convulsed the country since the contested presidential elections in June 2009. Thirty years ago, the Shah of Iran regarded the BBC Persian Service radio as his “enemy number one” and held it responsible for promoting the revolution of February 1979. Iranians are intrigued by the relationship between the BBC and the British Foreign and Commonwealth Office while academics, journalists and political and media analysts continue to debate the role of BBC language services around the world. What was the role of the BBC Persian Service in the Iranian revolution of 1979? Did the British Foreign Office interfere in the content of the daily broadcasts to Iran? Was the radio service a contributory force in the popular mobilization? Representatives from the BBC World Service, the Foreign and Commonwealth Office, Iranian officials and diplomats as well as independent journalists and writers who were active in that period are invited to tell their stories and debate the implications of that period. An invited audience will have a chance to ask questions. These witness accounts, which will be recorded live, will add significantly to our understanding of this crucial period in the contemporary history of Iran and the role of the BBCWS within the strategies of British public diplomacy. The event forms part of an on- going project on ‘diasporic nationalism’, part of the ‘Tuning In’ research on the BBC World Service funded through the AHRC Diasporas research programme. Speakers include Andrew Whitley and Lotfali Khonji; video-taped interviews with Lord David Owen and Fred Halliday.

Comment: I'm confused. This just looks like a transcription for a program teaser.